How to automatically load psd texture file in blender?
I am a new Blender user.
In Maya there is a feature to link pds file to draw texture and I can update it continuously when drawing just by pressing Ctrl + S to save that drawing. It will automatically change on Maya without any shortcut, but in Blender I need to do one more operation which is press Alt + R to actually download the latest drawing board on pts into Blender model.
Is there any way for me to just press once to save the pds file and Blender will automatically understand and change the texture according to the latest drawing board?

Looks like there might already be an addon for that.
